# 8'x8' platform 8' off the ground. If 4x4 steel columns, do I need bracing?

Tags: load-bearing, load

Remote off-grid land with lots of bears, coyotes and even turned wild domesticated dog packs.

I'd like to build a 8'x8'platform 8' off the ground for camping and use the bottom for storage.

If my corners are 4x4 .25 steel.

**Do I need bracing if only going to have about 400lb on top at any give time?
2x6 okay for deck support?**

It would have a custom ladder I can pull up. Trying to avoid bracing so it can't be climbed by animals (especially black bears). I've heard adult black bears can't reach things over 7.5' and can't really jump or do pullups.

Comment: How deep are you planning on making the posts?  Some angle bracing can help a lot with wobble if you can't dig very deep (if it's a rocky area).

Comment: I can dig deep and wide.  even 3'd x 2'w per if I have to.  soil is kinda sandy in central Florida.

Comment: Quarter inch steel seems excessive.

Comment: you could use use steel rods for bracing ... those would be harder to climb

Answer (score 1):

You could have a tremendous amount of dead weight on the platform without any trouble -- it's the liveliness of the load that causes problems. A single person weighing under 200 pounds can cause some sway in a 20,000+ pound bus by standing in the aisle and throwing his weight about, for instance. Consider the activities that will occur up there.

Have you considered a railing for fall safety? If the corner posts are chosen long enough to extend above platform level then they could support a railing; if the railing incorporates diagonal bracing or a shear plane (ie a sheet of plywood) it'll help stiffen the structure against swaying too (though not as much as bracing below the platform could do).

Does the storage of objects below the platform defeat the height of the platform? In other words, can the predators you're protecting against push the storage around and then use it as a step stool of sorts? If so then maybe you need to enclose the space beneath the platform. The enclosing walls could protect any bracing against being used by climbers.. but now the whole thing is starting to look a lot like a shed with a flat roof.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig the posts 3' into the ground and concrete them in, this will be a fine solution.  If it was a deck with a lot of movement on it, or if you wanted to hunt from the platform, I would say that bracing would be mandatory, but for your use case, the steel legs should be very sturdy.  There might be a little wiggle at the top when you walk, but I think you'd have to start exercising up there to really start to feel it.

For a little extra stiffness, you could use 2x10's for the skirts and bolt those to the beams.  I think that 2x6 is sturdy enough for the main floor, but the extra width on the skirt would be nice to really lock the legs together.

Comment: 3' really depends on where the OP lives. In Canada for example, that's above the frost line, which in a repeated freeze-thaw cycle, can push the posts up out of the ground, concrete or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer this sort of question with basic engineering and on-line data and calculators.

Here's a [calculator for beam deflection](https://www.epsilonengineer.com/single-load-cantilever-beam-deflection-calculator.html), assuming the beam is firmly fixed in concrete at the bottom.

The Young's Modulus for steel is [200Gpa](https://www.amesweb.info/Materials/Youngs-Modulus-of-Steel.aspx)

The moment of inertia for a 0.1m square beam is [0.000008333](https://calculators.io/moment-of-inertia/) (a hollow beam will be less stiff than a solid one, but not hugely so, and you have four beams, not just one.)

So a 100kg force (1000N) results in about 3mm of movement (or 1/8th of an inch)

Unless I've made a mistake - you should definitely check! (but it feels about right)